# Fetch separate header row and data row from a JSON response object in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am making an API call from Angular 5, the response is coming in below format.

```
{   "metadata":{
      "lastSyncTime":"2000-11-21T16:07:53",
      "dataFromDB":true
   },
   "allocationReports":[      {
         "allocatedUserCount":100,
         "healthGoalName":"Eat Healthier"
      },
      {
         "allocatedUserCount":130,
         "healthGoalName":"Feel Happier"
      },
  
      {
         "allocatedUserCount":150,
         "healthGoalName":"Quit Smoking"
      }
   ],
   "overall":{
      "usersWithGoalCount":0,
      "registeredCount":500,
      "eligibleCount":280
   }
}
```

I need implement a download functionality which needs data in a separate format like one header row and one data row.
So the download service requires data in below format.

Header row: `["Eat Healthier", "Feel Happier", "Quit Smoking"]`
Data row: `[100, 130, 150]`

The logic I have written is no working correctly. It is creating 6 different arrays. Can someone please help me with the logic.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should post your logic that does not work so you not only get the right answer, but can understand better where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done via `map` function:

```
// assuming the response body is stored in a variable called `response`:

const headerRow = response.allocationReports.map(report => report.healthGoalName))
const dataRow = response.allocationReports.map(report => report.allocatedUserCount))
```

To address the commenters concern about looping twice (which is NBD if readability and not clock cycles matter to you) here is an optimized version:

```
const headerRow = [];
const dataRow = [];
response.forEach(report => {
    headerRow.push(report.healthGoalName);
    dataRow.push(report.allocatedUserCount);
});
```

Comment: A map function will work, but you have to loop through once for the header, and once for the data.  A single for each would be better, especially if the list is much larger than 3 (although since it seems like this is aggregate data, it probably won't get very large)

Comment: @cjd82187 Its a common misconception that N loops of 1 line each is significantly slower than 1 loop with N lines. As N grows the difference between the two becomes smaller and smaller. If you are writing high performance code where every clock cycle matters, sure go nuts and optimize as much as you can. If that's not the case, even with arrays of 1K+ elements, the readability benefits of my answer far outweigh any savings you'll get